# Javascript changes variable when changing iFrame height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I build a script that changed the iframe height when the child is loaded in to the iframe. When I only console.log the value, it returns an integer. When I change the iframe height with the value the child send, the variable changed to the value that was the last time when the function worked. I almost spend one day to find out the bug.

The code in the child:

```
(function() {
                // your page initialization code here
                // the DOM will be available here
                window.parent.postMessage(
                    // get height of the content
                    document.body.scrollHeight
                    // set target domain
                    ,"*"
                )
            })();
        };
```

The code in the parent that gave the wright height:

```
function listenMessage(msg) {
        var before = msg.data;

        if(before % 1 === 0) {
          console.log(before);
        }
      }

      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);
      } else {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", listenMessage);
      }
```

The code in the parent that gave the wrong height:

```
function listenMessage(msg) {
        var before = msg.data;

        if(before % 1 === 0) {
          document.getElementById('receiver').height = before;
        }
      }

      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);
      } else {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", listenMessage);
      }
```

I hope someone can tell me the difference between the two parent codes.

Comment: I now know that it is document.getElementById('receiver').style.height but that is also not working.

Comment: I have now tested it with another div and that is working properly know. The only thing is that it does not work with the iframe...

Comment: try `var before = msg.data+'px';`

Comment: That does not work. The problem is that the value of the variable changes when I try to change the height of the iframe.

Comment: Can't really help much without a demo that we can use to access code

Comment: It works well when the new value is bigger than the old one. The old one causes the problem...

Comment: Here is the plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/zEuDg870ulZLmcZoqrJv?p=preview

Comment: So what steps replicate problem? I only get a message when frame loads first time

Comment: The problem is that the child does not use https so then clicking in the menu there will be an error. If you copy paste it and try it on your local machine everything will work.

Comment: Change the page to a large content page and then go back to home. You will see there will be a very big white space on the bottom of the page. The script thinks the scrollheight is the height from the bigger page and not the smaller one.

Comment: And what link is large content? Not interested in surfing whole site to figure it out

Comment: CATEGORIES --> AILE